# Faded Failure Feature

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Why now are some questions being so faded they cannot be properly read?  Is the new web page design an attempt to get people to talk about mathstack instead of talking about math?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, please?  My **guess** would be that you have ignored certain tags.  When you ignore a tag, questions with that tag are shown much less prominently.

Comment: Injective Function Example Proof shows up faided at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory

Comment: To me, the question you mentioned is not "faded."  What does it look like to you?  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Some items with negative scores appear faded to me, but when I move the mouse into them, they return to normal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the question you found "faded" in the [tag:elementary-set-theory] question list was so because it contains a tag you are ignoring.  Check your "ignored tags" list on the main site. I found something similar when I was looking at the question list of a specific tag. (Even quite negatively scored questions were not faded.)  If you click of "edit" on the ignored tags box/window you can choose between graying out or hiding questions with an ignored tag.

Comment: I have not ignored any tags because I do not know where the ignore tags list is.

Comment: I have not ignored any tags because I do not know where the ignore tags list is. @castoroccupatus

Comment: @GEdgar.  The faded ones I see have positive scores.    Who is responsible for design decisions?  Is the stack commercial?

Comment: It will all be *so much easier* if you just post a screenshot.

Comment: PLEASE post a screenshot.  I think it is clear that none of us understand what you are on about---a screenshot would really, really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not posted a screenshot, my best guess is that you have opted (perhaps accidentally) to "ignore" one or more tags.  In the screenshot below, I have "ignored" the [abstract algebra] tag (note the box on the bottom right labeled "Ignored Tags").  This means that any post tagged with [abstract algebra] will be greyed out (see the first question in the queue).

[image]

If this is what is going on and you want it to stop, hit the "edit" link in the "Ignored Tags" box (see below), and stop ignoring whatever tag is causing things to be greyed out.  Alternatively, hit the "edit" link and hide all questions with the ignored tag (then you won't see them at all, so the greyed-out questions won't clutter your feed).

[image]

Comment: It is possible that it was an accident, and some tag was ignored by mistake.

Comment: @WilliamElliot They were right to close the question.  It is unclear.  You were asked multiple times to provide screenshots and didn't, and you never replied to my question in the comments asking for clarification.  I still don't know what is *actually* happening on your end, because you have not clarified the question.  If the answer that I provided helps, I'm glad, but you didn't make it easy.  Oh, and please do not call other users "monsters."  It is kind of rude.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, Why did you accept this answer?  You claimed in a comment above that you "have not ignored any tags."  So how does this answer your question?  When you said you "have not ignored any tags," I assumed you were telling the truth.  In effect, I was not able to "accurately diagnose the trouble" because I trusted you.  And because of this I am a monster?

Comment: And why do you say that "the mob closed discussion"?  Only one user put your question on hold.  How is one person a "mob"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I have nothing against your answer.  I am just annoyed that the OP accused me of "not understanding the problem" (not knowing that the situation was caused by ignored tags) because I trusted his statement that he did not ignore any tags.

Comment: "they […] could not understand the problem"  Are you seriously saying that @castoroccupatus did "not understand the problem"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Regarding the comment that begins "I have nothing against your answer":  I agree entirely.  This topic has been rather frustrating from the start.  I only posted an answer because there is no nice way of putting screenshots into comments.